# Join two javascript arrays at index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this loop, the api returns markers fine, i want to add the url and the image inside the array.

```
let coordsList = [];

for (let i in markers) {
  let coords = markers[i].petLost.lostCoords;
  let url = petUrl + markers[i]._id;
  let image = petImage + markers[i].imageURL;
  coordsList.push(coords);
}
```

The result with this loop is:

```
[ 24.728216, 36.2308272 ] , [ 27.728216, 33.2308272 ] , ...
```

How can i inject in there the url and the image for each corresponding item in the array?

Desired result:

```
[ 24.728216, 36.2308272, http://blabla.html, http://image.jpg ] , 
[ 27.728216, 33.2308272, http://blabla2.html, http://image2.jpg ]
 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just try this:

```
let coords = markers[i].petLost.lostCoords;
let url = petUrl + markers[i]._id;
coords.push(url)
let image = petImage + markers[i].imageURL;
coords.push(image);
coordsList.push(coords);
```

The above snippet can become more elegant as below:

```
let markers = markers[i];
let markerData = markers.petLost
                        .lostCoords
                        .push(petUrl + markers._id) 
                        .push(petImage + markers.imageURL);
markersList.push(markerData);
```

*Note* I did a rename, in order to make it more meaningful and readable. If you follow this approach, you should replace the `coordsList`, wherever it is used with the `markersList`.